# how to map subarray by key of parent array reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

how to map subarray in react based on key of parent array?
[image]

I have tried mapping by id key of main array to map elements of dish_count array

```
<TableCell  align="left">
       {this.state.persons.map((items,name) => 
             <div key={this.state.persons.id}> 
    {(typeof(items.dish_count)=="object")? (<div>
              { items.dish_count.map((subdata) =>
                                    <table>
                                       <td >
                                         {subdata.meal_type}
                                         </td>
                                         </table>
                                  )
                                      }
                               </div>): (null)}</div>)}



                               </TableCell>
                               <TableCell align="left">    {this.state.persons.map((items,name) => 
                                <div key={this.state.persons.id} >{(typeof(items.dish_count)=="object")? (<div>
                                      {
                                       items.dish_count.map((subdata) =>

                                       <table>
                                       <td >
                                         {subdata.dish_count}
                                         </td>
                                         </table>
                                       )
                                      }
                               </div>): (null)}</div>)}</TableCell>
```

i want to map subarray dish_count by key id of parent array .I am able to map but the mapping is multiple and is not exclusive by parent array key.dish_count is the subarray of package array

persons array

```
 "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Gold",
                "dish_count": [
                    {
                        "dish_count": 4,
                        "meal_type": "Starters"
                    },
                    {
                        "dish_count": 4,
                        "meal_type": "Main Course"
                    },
                    {
                        "dish_count": 4,
                        "meal_type": "Dessert"
                    },
                    {
                        "dish_count": 4,
                        "meal_type": "Lunch"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Basic",
                "dish_count": [
                    {
                        "dish_count": 2,
                        "meal_type": "Starters"
                    },
                    {
                        "dish_count": 2,
                        "meal_type": "Main Course"
                    },
                    {
                        "dish_count": 2,
                        "meal_type": "Dessert"
                    },
                    {
                        "dish_count": 2,
                        "meal_type": "Lunch"
                    }
                ]
            }
]
```

I want 
          Meal Type     No of Dishes
  Gold    Starters      4
          Main Course   4
          Desert        4
          Lunch         4
Basic     Starters      2
          Main Course   2
          Desert        2
          Lunch         2

Comment: Can you show us the code for persons and how you expect your data to look like.

Comment: Yes i can show you the code for persons

Comment: You set persons to be an empty string, that does not work with map. The console.log will not display the persons because setState is async. The state will be set later, use the callback of setState to get the persons:  this.setState({persons:res.data.data.data},
       () => console.log('package',this.state.persons)
    );

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems in your code:

1. `this.state({persons:''});`: This will set the initial persons to be an empty string and will fail with map.
2. `console.log('package',this.state.persons)`: setState is async and the console.log will not print the desired state but the previous state. Use the callback of setState as second parameter to access the new state:

   ```
   this.setState({persons:res.data.data.data}, () => console.log('package',this.state.persons) );
   ```
3. `this.state.persons.map((items, name) =>`: The map function will provide different parameters: the first is the person and the second is the index of that person within the array.
4. `div key = {this.state.persons.id}`: since persons is an array, the key will be undefined. If you use the map function correctly, you can use person.id.

When you fixed these problems, the code should work as expected.

To only show the expected dishes per person and not to print the duplication you have to write it like this:

```
class Table extends React.Component {       
    render() {
        return <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Meal Type</td>
                    <td>Number of Dishes</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {this.state.persons.map(person =>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{person.id}</td>
                        <td>{person.name}</td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                              <tbody>
                                   {person.dish_count.map(dish => <tr>
                                         <td>{dish.meal_type}</td>
                                     </tr>
                                     )}
                              </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                              {person.dish_count.map(dish => <tr >
                                  <td>{dish.dish_count}</td>
                               </tr>
                               )}
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )
            }
        </tbody>
    </table >
    }
}
```

By not iterating over the person for each sub-table, you can remove the duplicated data.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Domino987/pen/rNBLqLp?editors=0010)

Hope this helps.

Comment: any other techniques for this problem

Comment: I see you fixed your code. Can you show us how persons looks and what exactly the current error is?

Comment: key={this.state.persons.id} wont work because this.state.persons is an array, use items.id.

Comment: I tried the above thing but the mapping is multiple  times the data.

Comment: How does persons look like pls. Can you post the array?

Comment: I wrote a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Domino987/pen/rNBLqLp?editors=0010) for you. Does that work for you?

Comment: above is the persons array to be mapped

Comment: Yes i looked at it will try now

Comment: I tried your codepen but i want mapping by id of parent array i.e persons.In persons array i have 2 names Gold and basic which have id 1 & 2.i want id to be key for subarray

Comment: Can you show a picture how you want your table to look like? It is not clear, how you want your table to look sorry.

Comment: In the above image i want 4 in gold column and 2 in basic col .There is multiple mapping instead of single mapping

Comment: 4 of what exactly? Rows? Columns? Dishes? Can you maybe provide an image on how you want it, not how it is? Like draw it ? I don't understand how you want it to look.

Comment: I updated my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Domino987/pen/rNBLqLp?editors=0010). Does that work for you?